# No more authentication methods to try. Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

I have set up a home network behind a router a while ago and use openssh to access the network consisting of my laptop, wife's netbook and my desktop all running l/x/ubuntu 12.04. This worked perfectly for some time.

I am now only able to access from and to the netbook and the other 2, but no access between the laptop and desktop. I have never used the id_* route so have no id_* files in the ~/.ssh directories.

I have tried various strategies advised on forums such as this one eg. deleting the known_hosts and changing the configuration files such as the PasswordAuthentication to no, yes and commented out. None of which works.

The only thing I can think of is that my recent tinkering with setting up a vpn network between the laptop and desktop may have changed something to disrupt the working of ssh between these 2 machines. btw I have not managed to get the vpn to work yet (see previous post on this forum).

The /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on my desktop is:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp #/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

Match User sftpuser #group sftponly
ChrootDirectory /media/Backups/ftp
X11Forwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes 
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

The ssh -v laptop command outputs:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/malapradej/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/malapradej/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for laptop
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.2 [192.168.0.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/malapradej/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/malapradej/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/malapradej/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/malapradej/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/malapradej/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/malapradej/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 1e:f2:57:81:28:8a:12:d3:7e:2d:04:c2:82:4f:43:72
debug1: Host '192.168.0.2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/malapradej/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/malapradej/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/malapradej/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/malapradej/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Please clarify how you are trying to connect the two: ssh? Also, what is the effect, an error message (if any) will help.

Comment: hi crafter. Yes using ssh. I added the full error log above.

Comment: Can you clarify which direction you are trying to connect (desktop to laptop?) and which `sshd_config` file you have posted?

Comment: Check your permissions in .ssh. Try 700 for .ssh. 600 for .ssh/* . Also check who created them : you or root.

Comment: the connection was from desktop to laptop and the sshd_config file is for the desktop.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thnx for the help. That solved it. My permissions needed to be set as 700 for .ssh. 600 for .ssh/*, **making sure you do it on both machines**. Also change the ownership of .ssh/. and .ssh/* to the user from root, otherwise any information in the config file will not be accessible to the user.

```
sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
sudo chown -R User ~/.ssh/
sudo chgrp -R User ~/.ssh/
```

where User is the user name.
This worked for me.

Comment: +1. Another scenario where this answer is useful: you mistakenly copied authorized_keys file on the server from one user to another to speed up the process.

Comment: you also need to make sure you home/username directory has the right permissions. in my case, i had to change it to 751 = chmod 751 /home/username

Comment: not having executable permission on ~/.ssh was the problem for me. it was 600 on ~/.ssh and changing it to 700 did the trick for me. Learnt it the hard way though scratching my head a few hours . 
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work

Comment: Did anybody tell you that you are awesome !!! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

I know that this may sounds as a stupid advice.
But we had this issue: the connection was ok, and after sometime, it stopped to work. 
As once the connection is active, it was impossible to know when the authentication stopped to effective. 
In our case, while changing the keys for other users, that specific key was also changed. So new connections did not work, but current connections stay alive.

I do suggest that you always keep the pubkey and privkey together in somewhere, so, you can compare and even reload. Another thing is, try to do a ssh connection to guarantee that it is not a fingerprint issue. 
In both cases -v, -vv and -debug for sshfs may be useful. Also, in the host machine, use journalctl -f while trying to connect, it will show the attempt (if it happen) so you be sure that the connection is not blocked too...

Comment: `journalctl -f` was very helpful: ` Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory ...` nice one

Answer (score 1):

Also check if you don't have a config file in `~/.ssh` and there is no entry `PubkeyAuthentication=no`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found below error msg in the debug info

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:/m/qEkp4FQbzgofk3iHUDVfyjpZMFxX68UKPoTc766k
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:zTtrWi58QpPYwpzilta5vfmne6FFJ0C2J7ucmZI95U8
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

And found there are multi files in my ~/.ssh/ folder with below detail:

```
~/.ssh# ls
authorized_keys  config  config.bak  id_ed25519  id_ed25519.pub  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

### I removed the all id_* files except id_rsa and my problem solved.